# PHP Mailer can't send emails using my work internet connection

Tags: php, email, networking, port, mailer

i'm developing a website to send reminders to employees in my company using phpmailer, the emails are working fine, but when i connect to the workplace internet connection it stops working with no errors but:
Connection: opening to smtp.mail.yahoo.com:587, timeout=300, options=array ( )

i'm guessing it might be a closed port, so i tried using 587 and 25.
i'm not that good in networking, is there's any way i can know what is the exact error?

```
function SendOutlook(){
    //$recipient = 'xxxxx@yahoo.com';
    require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
    $Emp_recipient = "employee@yahoo.com";
    $mail = new PHPMailer;

    $mail->SMTPDebug = 4;                               // Enable verbose debug output

    $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
    $mail->Host = "smtp.mail.yahoo.com";   // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username = 'xxxxx@yahoo.com';                 // SMTP username (server username)
    $mail->Password = 'xxxxx';                           // SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
    $mail->Port = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to

    $mail->setFrom('xxxxx@yahoo.com', 'One');
    $mail->addAddress($Emp_recipient,"name");     // Add a recipient

    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
    $mail->Subject = 'test';
    $mail->Body    = "scheduled on your outlook calender";

    if(!$mail->send()) {
        echo 'Message could not be sent.';
        echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
        exit();
    }else {
        echo '<p>Message has been sent</p>';
    }
    echo !extension_loaded('openssl')?"Not Available":"Available";

}
```

Comment: You should be more verbose when you describe the working and the non-working case, because so far I'm not sure if the only difference is the "workplace internet connection" or if something in the script is different too and since it probably is put on some server, if the servers are different too ... your whole setup is unclear to me.

Comment: i'm using the same script and server the only different is the internet connection